# Facebook AuthHash storage in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am trying to authenticate using facebook in my application, This is done using omniauth and devise gems. The problem is that when the AuthHash returns, it has too much data which I want to use in my application. I don't want to store it in my db, since it is a single time usage data. But need to store it temporarily somewhere, but clearly session is too small for such a huge data.

Can I store convert the auth hash to JSON and store it db and then read from it using JSON.parse? Is it a good practice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach to the issue, which might or might not suit you:

I execute the "to_json" method for the data retrieved, in order to make the object a "JSON" one:

```
logger.info(request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_json)
```

Then I aim to store it in a "metadata" table temporarily, then process them later with a worker and remove them.